# Getting list of values from list of options

Tags: list, f#

I have a simple list of string options, like this:

```
let myList = [ None; Some "foo"; Some "bar" ]
```

I tried to get the non-empty values from the list using this approach:

```
myList
|> List.filter Option.isSome
|> List.map Option.get
```

But then I found another code somewhere on the Internet:

```
myList
|> List.choose id
```

They both do the exact same thing. Are there any performance differences between those two code samples? Or is it just about code preference?

Comment: I would imagine the second option should work faster because it traverses the list only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first code (filter + map) does this:

1. (Recursively) loop through `myList` applying `Option.isSome` function (pattern matching happens here) to each item and building a new list of items where function returned `true`

   `[Some "foo"; Some "bar"]`
2. (Recursively) loop through the new list applying `Option.get` function (also pattern matching) to each item and building yet another new list of values returned from the function

   `["foo"; "bar"]`

The second approach (choose) does this:

1. (Recursively) loop through `myList` applying `id` function to each item and building a new list of items where function retuned `Some` (only one pattern matching)

So it's twice less job done and much less code to write and maintain.

`choose` is an idiomatic way to 'unwrap' options skipping those which None. That's why it exists in all collection modules.